# Would this soft question be appropriate?

Tags: support, specific-question, on-topic

A few weeks back on the Math Stack Exchange, I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317170/what-conditions-constrain-pdes-which-are-studied-in-practice) about "interesting" PDEs. It got (no answers and) some deserved criticism, so I opened [a discussion on the Meta there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/was-this-soft-question-appropriate) and made some pretty big edits in response to feedback, without changing the question I'd intended to ask. There hasn't been much feedback since then, and in particular still no answers.

This all leaves me with no sense of whether

- the (soft) question I actually meant to ask was bad,
- the presentation was still unacceptable after my edits,
- anything else.

I got a hunch that reposting the question here might get better results, but am aware that at least the presentation is still less than ideal (that's never been my strong suit) and maybe there's just nothing salvageable. So, I'd be very grateful for any and all advice.

Comment: It's too hard to find a clear question in the post. The paragraphs seem to be a quote, a comment on previous versions, "P should be well-defined", "...would obviously be too much", then something of unclear relevance...so by the time I hit "to recap" I give up.

Comment: Maybe try: "What mathematical properties are shared by most PDEs which are of interest in applications?"

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the negative votes on this question. Are they meant to be proxies for saying "no, the original question would not be appropriate" (in which case, more feedback would be appreciated), or was asking about this bad in itself for some reason?

Comment: @MattF. Thanks for confirming my suspicion that presentation is still a problem. I've spent quite a while on rewording already and could really use some help, but appreciate that it's my responsibility.

Comment: I expect the downvotes are either “I don’t want that question on this site” or “I don’t want questions about an MSE post on MathOverflow Meta”